# MessageFormat in javascript (parameters in localized UI strings)

Tags: javascript, regex, internationalization

What is a good way for handling parameters in localized strings in javascript?
I am using the same format as in java's MessageFormat class, e.g.:

`There are {0} apples in basket ID {1}.`

Where `{0}` will be replaced with the first parameter and `{1}` with the second.

This is the call I want to use in JS (i.e. I want to implement `origStr`):

`var str = replaceParams(origStr, [5, 'AAA']);`

I am guessing the best strategy would be to use a regular expression. If so, please offer a good regular expression. But I'm open to hear any other options.

Comment: Shows how immature JS is :(

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
String.prototype.format = function() {
    var args = arguments;

    return this.replace(/\{(\d+)\}/g, function() {
        return args[arguments[1]];
    });
};

// Returns '2 + -1 = 1'.
'{0} + {1} = {2}'.format(2, -1, 1);
```

Or to fit your requirement:

```
function replaceParams(string, replacements) {
    return string.replace(/\{(\d+)\}/g, function() {
        return replacements[arguments[1]];
    });

    // Or, if prototype code above...
    String.format.apply(string, replacements);
}
```

You can add fancy i18n features such as ordinal-i-fying (whatever it's called):

```
// Not well tested.

i18n.en.filters = {
    ordinal: function(n) {
        // FIXME Doesn't handle all cases.
        switch(('' + n).substr(-1)) {
            case '1':
                return '' + n + 'st';
            case '2':
                return '' + n + 'nd';
            case '3':
                return '' + n + 'rd';
            case '4':
            case '5':
            case '6':
            case '7':
            case '8':
            case '9':
            case '0':
                return '' + n + 'th';
            default:
                return n; // Just in case...
        }

    },
    plural: function(n, singular, plural) {
        if(n == 1) {
            return singular;
        } else {
            return plural;
        }
    }
};

i18n.current = i18n.en;

String.prototype.format = function() {
    var args = arguments;

    return this.replace(/\{((\d+)((\|\w+(:\w+)*)*))\}/g, function() {
        var arg = args[arguments[2]],
            filters = arguments[3].split('|'),
            i, curFilter, curFilterArgs, curFilterFunc;

        for(i = 0; i < filters.length; ++i) {
            curFilterArgs = filters[i].split(':');
            curFilter = curFilterArgs.shift();
            curFilterFunc = i18n.current.filters[curFilter];

            if(typeof curFilterFunc === 'function') {
                arg = curFilterFunc.apply(null, [ arg ].concat(curFilterArgs));
            }
        }

        return arg;
    });
};

'You have {0} {0|plural:cow:cows} but I have {1} {1|plural:cow:cows}.'.format(2,1);
'My horse came in {0|ordinal} place while yours came in {1|ordinal}.'.format(42,1);
```

Answer (score 10):

Looks like I was only about 3 years late, but in case anyone still needs an actual standalone MessageFormat library for JS:

https://github.com/SlexAxton/messageformat.js

There ya go! Compiles to JS - so it can be really speedy, and supports `SelectFormat` and `PluralFormat`.

Note:: This is ICU MessageFormat which is a bit different (read: better) than the stuff that might be built into your language.

Comment: Gotta say, this is a little different to what I expected. We use ICU MessageFormat in Java, and it looks more like {0,plural, zero{no results} one{1 result} other{{0} results}}. Whereas this one looks like {RES, plural, =0{no results} one{1 result} other{# results} } - other than superficially using the same CLDR keywords for one/other/etc. it seems like a completely different format to me.

Comment: MessageFormat.js and MessageFormat.java only happen to share names.  The syntax is completely different.

Comment: They're the same format, and are mostly compatible with each other actually. The two examples @Trejkaz mention there only differ in which keywords are being used. `=0` is a literal value, where `zero` is a keyword (that doesn't apply to en-US).

Comment: "Doesn't apply", but works totally fine as far as we can tell, and is useful for differentiating messages when talking about "no things".

Answer (score 1):

@strager answer did not really work for me, but with a little tweak i got it to be just what i was looking for (which is very similar to what @Omesh was aiming to).

```
String.prototype.format = function() {
    var args = arguments;

    return this.replace(/\{(\d+)\}/g, function(a) {
        return args[0][parseInt(a.match(/(\d+)/g))];
    });
};
```

Notice the index value of the args array is different.

It should be called just like @strager suggests:

```
'I like {0} and {1} but not {2}'.format('apples', 'oranges', 'kiwi');
```