# how to concat persian characters with english characters in righ order in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to concat:

> "2334" , "234", "محمد"
>
> in order which "2334" be the first and "محمد" be the second and "234"
>   in the third place

how can i do this in javascript?
thanks.

Comment: what is the logic behind putting persian character in the second place?

Comment: *concat persian characters with english characters* - Was that the Shah of Iran?

Comment: i did not used any logic, just concatinating them with + operator

Comment: @MohammadHajiaghazadeh in that case persian characters should stay in the third place, but you want them at second place. What is the rationale?

Comment: @gurvinder372 yes, i want "محمد" be in the second place

Comment: @gurvinder372 cause it is vehicle number, and that is in this format

Comment: In which context do you want it to be in this order ? It mainly depends on the output text direction. Internally, for js processor it will be the one you set but if your output is configured to show persian as right to left, this part will be displayed after. like if we set `var first = "2334"
var second = "234"
var third =  "محمد"`;` then `first+third+second` will output
`"2334محمد234"` in my console, but `(first+third+second).split('')` will output every character in the right order.

Comment: @MohammadHajiaghazadeh so if `var arr = ["2334" , "234", "محمد"]`, output should be `var output = arr[0] + arr[2] + arr[1];` ?

Comment: @gurvinder372 thanks , i used array to handel it, i saved it with space between this three and then for view in html i split it.

Comment: @gurvinder372 output = arr[0] + arr[2] + arr[1];     this does not output in the right order

Comment: @MohammadHajiaghazadeh  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353408/messageformat-in-javascript-parameters-in-localized-ui-strings/1353411#1353411

Answer (score 2):

One way to make this work is to wrap these distinct parts in tags, like a `span` and indicate the direction with the `dir` attribute (alternatively it could be done with CSS):

```js
var arr = ["2334" , "234", "محمد"];
var output = '<span dir="auto">' + arr[0] + '</span>' +
             '<span dir="auto">' + arr[2] + '</span>' + 
             '<span dir="auto">' + arr[1] + '</span>';

document.body.innerHTML = output;
```

Comment: `auto` works but `ltr, rtl, ltr` outputs `234xxx2334` instead of `2334xxx234` for me

Comment: I saw you also noticed that `dir` needs to be set on every span ;-)

Comment: Indeed. The test data could have been more distinct to spot the total reversal. Hadn't noticed it at first.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
function wrap(str) {
    return '\u202B' + str + '\u202C';
}

var arr = ["2334" , "234", "محمد"];
var output = arr[0] + wrap(arr[2]) + arr[1];
document.body.innerHTML += output;
```

Comment: doesn't work on my FF, but works on my chrome (osX 10.9 set as english)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to output it in an html page and get it displayed in this order, simply wrap all your string parts into spans and add a `display:inline-block` rule on the spans :

```js
var arr = ["2334" , "234", "محمد"];
document.body.innerHTML = '<span>'+arr[0]+'</span><span>'+arr[2]+'</span><span>'+arr[1]+'</span>';
```

```css
body>span{ display: inline-block; }
```

Comment: Works fine for me as well.

Comment: Yep, since all elements are now separated, browser doesn't care about the `dir` anymore.

Answer (score 1):

for this purpose you can use unicode. i hope it will help you and sorry if i wrote something wrong

```js
var str = '123' + '\u06a6\u069e\u0681' + '456';
document.querySelector('.result').innerHTML = str;
```

```css
.result {
  unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
  direction: ltr;
}
```

```html
<p class="result"></p>
```

Comment: It looks like the foreign word has its letters in the wrong direction.